# how to implement one radio button to be active while selecting it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having table view and on table view cell the radio button has been placed and the radio buttons may increase or decrease dynamically when I select one radio button the other buttons should not active at a time here is the code I used for selecting a button but I am unable to make other button inactive at a time

```
 func paymentMethodURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.paymentmethodURL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
             self.paymentmethodsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "payment method") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
func paymentreviewURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.paymentReviewURL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            let arrayss = jsonObj?.allKeys
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {

    } else{

    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return paymentmethodsArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let paymentcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for:indexPath) as! paymentTableViewCell
    tableDetails.isHidden = false
    myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    let arr = self.paymentmethodsArray[indexPath.row]
    paymentcell.paymentNameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
    return paymentcell
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're looking to do, and your code is just a stub.

Comment: i having radio buttons on three cells if i click on a radio button the other button should be inactive but i am unable to do it

Comment: this is my one radio button action

Comment: When user taps on second radio button while first is active, I want to deactivate first and make second active @OwenHartnett

Comment: create `button` outlet inside cell class, and use my code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var checkIsRadioSelect = [Int]()
  var  webserviceArray = [modelObj]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let obj = webserviceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
    let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: obj.wateverUniqeId)
    if(checkIndex != nil){
          cell.radioButton.isSelected = true


    }else{
         cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
    }
}

@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let obj = webserviceArray[sender.tag]
 let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of:obj.wateverUniqeId)
    if sender.isSelected {
        self.checkIsRadioSelect.remove(at: sender.tag)
    } else{
        if(chekIndex == nil){

            self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(obj.wateverUniqeId)

        }

    } self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i am having two buttons to show or hide depending on the radio button  active any idea how to implement this @amri rt ?

Comment: You should ask different question for this for better understanding

Comment: no thanks i got that another problem that i am having web services in that i am getting default key value pair in that 1 and 0 will be coming by using that  i need to set the radio button active when app loads first time and later on i need to change it manually that answer already u posted if possible any idea how to implement @ami rt ?

Comment: Simple, you have to use that `value` (key,value) instead `indexpath.row` in `checkIsRadioSelect` array and when you click on radio button first you get that `value` from related array which you use to store all the object and then  instead of `let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)` use `let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: whteverObj.value)`

Comment: but i need to have both that is to change manually and depending on web services for first time app loads is it possible with it  @ami rt

Comment: when you call the web service you have to append all value inside `checkIsRadioSelect`

Comment: when you click manually on RadioButton , you have to get object of array using `sender.tag (i.e array[sender.tag])` then `let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: whteverObj.value)` and then same as above

Comment: didn't got as expected @ami rt

Comment: i think i am not getting your exact point what you want to ask..Can you please describe it briefly?

Comment: for the first time app loads at that time the radio button should be active depending on the web services data and after loading we are able to change it manually by selecting after loading the app @amri rt

Comment: it also didn't work when i run the app at that time i didn't enable according to my data @ami rt

Answer (score 1):

you should like this:

```
 var tagSelected = -1
```

//assume each radio button have tag 0 1 2

```
@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
    tagSelected = sender.tag 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

//cell for RowAtIndexPath

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
   kCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? YourCell else {
   fatalError("Cell is not dequeued")
   }

   //logic for match indexPath.row /section to your button tags
   if indexPath.row == tagSelected {
   //selected here your radio button
   } else {
   //unselect all others
   }
    //other code

  return cell
 }
```

Comment: but i am having dynamical array is it suits for that @SuryaKantSharma ?

Comment: how to give tag for dynamical arrays ?

Comment: i had modified just check n help me

Comment: i am having two buttons to show or hide depending on the radio button active any idea how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple solution is to have an integer for exemple to hold the index of the cell containing the selected button, for exemple at t=0 none is selected so say initial value for this new variable would be -1, once the user select button in cell 3 , u put 3 in that new variable , and later when he select cell 5 first you check if the variable has a valid index in it (in this case 3) then you go unselect the radio in cell 3 (which u have its index) and then select cell 5 and so on and so on..
now in your case I take it that IBAction is inside you cell controller, so you dont have direct access to the tableview and other cells to "deselect" if needed, what I would do is create a delegate protocol for that cell and have the viewcontroller containing the tableview be its delegate so whenever the user select a button i just invoke the delegate method with the cell's index as parameter and obviously implement this delegate method in the viewcontroller and do as I said earlier, here s an exemple on how it would go :
in the cell controller :

```
@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {

    if sender.isSelected {

    } else{
      self.delegate?.selectButton(index: self.index)
      //invoke the delegate so that the viewcontroller deselect any other cell that might be selected
    }
}
```

and in the viewcontroller :

```
func selectButton(index: index) {
     if self.selectedCell != -1 {
       let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndex(IndexPath(0, self.selectedCell))
        cell.selectRadioButton(cell.button)
     }
     self.selectedCell = index
}
```

Comment: i tried ur method but unable to implement @Hussein Dimessi

Comment: i need to call func selectButton(index: index) in didselect row at indexpath method or which method ?

Comment: the selectButton is a delegate method, you create a delegate protocol that only have this method and then give the cell a delegate property and then assign the viewcontroller as that delegate